# Get a term and its subterms in Sharepoint with jsom

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, taxonomy

I manage to obtain all the terms of a set of terms but I am only interested in obtaining a specific term and its subtermines. I have followed the answer to this question https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78514/accessing-terms-in-term-store-using-jsom-in-sharepoint-2013 but I only need to get one term and I can't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code snippet like below:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   

    var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "_layouts/15/";

    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function(){

                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js",function(){
                
                execOperation('3797f7a9-7902-47c1-a5bb-44b6ccaca1b4');
                
                }); 

            });
        }
    );

});

function execOperation(parentTermId) {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var session = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
    var termStore = session.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
    
    //var parentTermId = '3797f7a9-7902-47c1-a5bb-44b6ccaca1b4'; //parent Term Id
    var parentTerm = termStore.getTerm(parentTermId);
    var terms = parentTerm.get_terms();  //load child Terms
    
    
    context.load(terms);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
    function(){
       //print child Terms
       for(var i = 0; i < terms.get_count();i++){
           var term = terms.getItemAtIndex(i);
           console.log(term.get_name());
           if(term.get_termsCount() > 0)
           {
              execOperation(term.get_id());
           }
           
       }
    
    }, 
    function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());    
    });

}
 
</script>
```

Reference:

[SharePoint2013 Taxonomy get all child term of a specific parent term using JSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103430/sharepoint2013-taxonomy-get-all-child-term-of-a-specific-parent-term-using-jsom)

Update with some details about debugging code snippet for your reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you first, I had to make some changes but it worked. How could I get the children of the children

Comment: Replace the Term Id with the child term's in the code snippet and then it will return the children of the children :)

Comment: But how can I get it to be called over and over again ie in a way. You could add it to your answer.

Comment: Please see the updated code, just checking the termsCount for a term and then recall the function recursively :-)

Comment: Thank you very much it seems to work. A bit silly question. What library are you getting the term methods from? For example term.get_id

Comment: It's from SP.Taxonomy.js, you can check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/dn312546(v=office.15), and a smart way to check method is using Developer Tool (F12) by adding a break point, see the capture in the answer :-)

Comment: Sorry how could I know when the executeQueryAsync method finishes executing for the last time

Comment: Add a breakpoint in Developer Tool, when executeQueryAsync finished executing， it will call the for loop and console.log term name...
And from your questions above, I guess you know less about SharePoint Jsom, then you can learn about it with this document firstly:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/dn168907(v=office.15)